Did you receive the newsletter for this week (September 27) on Meta Stack Exchange?
I usually receive the newsletter for Meta Stack Exchange on every Friday, at 3am (Malaysia time). But this week, I still haven’t received the newsletter for Meta Stack Exchange for Sep 27 (yesterday). Now, my time is Saturday, at 10pm.
I have searched in my spam/junk folders, but I don’t see any newsletter on that folder.
I also did some searching on my Gmail, but I still haven’t got the newsletter for this week, see the picture below:



The last newsletter I received for Meta Stack Exchange was on September 20.
Am I the only person who has not received the newsletter, or hasn’t it been sent to anyone?
I search this question for this site, and found this: Meta Stack Exchange newsletter is not delivered on December 25
I don’t know if the link above is a duplicate or not.

I got it two days ago, 7 days after the previous, i.e. no repro.

There seems to be more going on: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/403205/did-you-receive-the-newsletter-for-this-week-september-27-on-meta-stack-exchan
