I received the Super User newsletter 27 times. Is there something wrong with the newsletter settings?
I received the Super User newsletter from 08.10.2024 multiple times. This is very annoying since I still receive "new" emails with the same newsletter. Every email has the same time stamp and content. However, I receive the one after another.  
My email address is: aar**@*********.de
Is that happening to anyone else too?
Can anyone check the settings for do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email?
Or what can I do?

I got one couple of days ago and it was fine. (Not SU, but don't think it matters)

You probably got all the letters missing for other people: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/403205/237989 :P

How did it jump from 10 to 22? You still get them?

This is the dreaded EmailOverflow ... That e-mail address is very early, alphabetically speaking. Reminds me of a bug at work where somebody got a huge number of invoices for a magazine subscription, just because she was the first customer on the list.

@ShadowWizardyes... meanwhile, I received another 5... so, 27 in total

It seems as if the issue is solved. I don't get any extra mails anymore. Thanks!
